# No puedo guardar el símbolo "+" al momento de hacer una peticion Post en angular

Tags: angular, post

```
      createContent(data): Observable<any>{
    var  headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('token')
    });
    const url = this.env.rootUrl+'API/SERIES/POST_CREATE_SERIE'
    const data_info = new HttpParams()
    .set('name', "prueba + prueba")
    .set('description', data.description)
    .set('url_route', data.url_portada)
    ;
    
    return this.http.post(url, data_info, {headers:headers})
  }
```

El problema es que al momento de mandar la petición el campo name se guarda como prueba prueba sin el "+", de hecho lo agrega como un espacio.

Answer (score 0):

Si no es estricto que data_info sea una instancia de HttpParams, podrías mandar la información como un json.

```
let data_info = {name: 'prueba + prueba', description: data.description, url_route: data.url_portada};
return this.http.post(url, data_info, {headers:headers});
```

Comment: pero eso es algo que llenan los usuarios. en la vista les aparece el formulario para crear el contenido. ahi solo tomo los datos que ellos introducen, le puse "prueba + prueba" para que se entendiera más a lo que me refiero

Answer (score 0):

La cosa es que, desde [este punto (commit en GitHub)](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/789a47e#diff-dc37c8bd8a489909b943d79ba0a2316cR376), Angular tiene este comportamiento específico por defecto.

De acuerdo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428842/angular-url-plus-sign-converting-to-space) y sus respuestas, hay al menos dos caminos (con variantes).

- El camino 1 es escapar todo antes de ponerlo como parámetro de tu petición:

```
let encodedName = encodeURI('"prueba + prueba"');
const data_info = new HttpParams()
    .set('name', encodedName)...
```

Y después podrás recuperar todo haciendo el proceso inverso

`let decodedValue = decodeURI(encodedValue);`

- El camino 2 es hacerle override al intercerptor con el que Angular escapa caracteres. Algo como

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpParams, HttpParameterCodec } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class EncodeHttpParamsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const params = new HttpParams({encoder: new CustomEncoder(), fromString: req.params.toString()});
    return next.handle(req.clone({params}));
  }
}


class CustomEncoder implements HttpParameterCodec {
  encodeKey(key: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  encodeValue(value: string): string {
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  decodeKey(key: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(key);
  }

  decodeValue(value: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  }
}
```

y luego usarlo en la sección de providers de tu `app.module.ts`

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: EncodeHttpParamsInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
]
```

Hay algunas otras opciones allí que han variado a medida que ha evolucionado Angular. Puedes pasar por la pregunta citada y revisar.